# Is there a way to categorize jasmine tests and manage exclusions

Tags: testing, jasmine, categories

In NUnit, it is possible to create test categories in order to better manage the whole test suite. In ReSharper, you can easily exclude tests based on these categories.

I'm looking for a way to exclude my Jasmine tests from running with the whole test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xit instead of it in your specs. Or dont include the js with your specs in the test runner html.

Comment: xit or xdescribe was exactly what I needed.  Thanks

Comment: What would you do to exclude some tests on a build and exclude some others tests on a different build?  I use Visual Studio with asp.net.  I could separate the tests on different projects and them run the tests on specific DLLs but I'd rather find a way to categorize my unit tests like I do with NUnit. Any other idea ?